# Do all Remans have telepathic abilities?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-nemesis

Are all Remans telepathic like Shinzon's viceroy, from *Star Trek: Nemesis*, who has considerable telepathic abilities?

Comment: Well, they're really big on sums...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Possibly Yes**

In the films and series no other Remans have shown this ability.

However we haven't seen too many Remans, Nero doesn't display any telepathic talent in Star Trek 2009, nor do any of his crew.

**BUT** According to the novel trilogy *Vulcan's Soul*

> The Remans were descended from the telepathic Vulcans who refused to give up their abilities during the exodus to Romulus, and were enslaved by the majority non-telepaths who became the Romulans.

Implying that the whole race as a whole have telepathy. 
Maybe some are better at it than others or just choose not to use it.

So, despite initially thinking they don't and the viceroy is a special case, the evidence from the book leads me to think **YES** but to varying degrees.

Comment: i think the whole mind meld thing, is the telepathic part between vulcans/romulans

Comment: I think this answer needs a bit of reorganizing: your facts seem sound, but your first and last sentences contradict each other...

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I'm trying to show that the films don't show anyone else using them, so would initially say no, but a book says they have them, leading me to conclude yes.

Comment: ah, ok. It's still a bit confusing as written; I'd recommend you put what you just said right up front then you can explain it afterwards.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield cheers, how's it read now?